# Read from Popen object's stdout while it's running

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-multithreading, popen

I'm trying to capture the stdout of a Popen object while it's running and display this data on a gui and log it. However whenever I try and read from the stdout attribute my program freezes. Minimal working code below. 'here' prints, then the process string representation, but then it hangs when it tries to read the first byte of stdout. Why is this the case?

Main script

```
import subprocess
import os
from threading import Thread


def print_to_terminal(process):
    print(process)
    print(process.stdout.read(1), flush=True)
    sys.stdout.flush()


runner = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'print_and_wait.py'], env=os.environ, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print('here')
t = Thread(target=print_to_terminal, args=[runner]).run()
print('there')
runner.wait()
```

script Popen is calling

```
from time import sleep


for _ in range(10):
    print('hello')
    sleep(1)
```

After comments: This did work if I added a flush to the print in the `print_and_wait` function. See below

```
from time import sleep


for _ in range(10):
    print('hello', flush=True)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Note that when stdout isn't to a TTY, it's buffered by default.

Comment: Right.  Add `sys.stdout.flush()` after your print and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Or just use `flush=True` when calling `print()`